# Beaglebone Black - Enable SPI Interface

Tags: spi, beagleboneblack

I'm looking to use the MAX31865 (http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/7963) with my Beaglebone Black running Ubuntu 12.0.4.  The kernel is a standard 3.8.13-bone30 kernel.  Having an SPI interface, I was hoping to interface with the development kit using SPI0 on the Beaglebone Black.  Unfortunately every time I enter

```
ls /dev/spi*
```

the result is

```
ls: cannot access /dev/spi*: No such file or directory
```

I attempted to follow the directions here: http://hipstercircuits.com/enable-spi-with-device-tree-on-beaglebone-black-copy-paste/

When I copied the compiled file over to /lib/firmware I noticed that there were three other spi related files.  Those are

```
BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dtbo
BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo
BB-SPIDEV1A1-00A0.dtbo
```

In addition, the command

```
echo BB-SPI1-01 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots
```

returns

```
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

I've tried the same in Angstrom with no success.  Can anyone assist me in getting the SPI interface working?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you should only use the file names appeared in the dir. For example instead of "BB-SPI1-01", you should use "BB-SPIDEV0" or "BB-SPIDEV1" ... etc
Also don't forgot to replace the * in "bone_capemgr.*" with a number, it's 8 for me.

here are my steps:
1)

```
root@beaglebone:/# cat /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots
0: 54:PF---
1: 55:PF---
2: 56:PF---
3: 57:PF---  
4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G  
5: ff:P-O-L Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
```

notice, there are only 0-5 items

2) cd to the /lib/firmware folder

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# ls *SPI*
ADAFRUIT-SPI0-00A0.dtbo  BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dts   BB-SPIDEV1A1-00A0.dtbo
ADAFRUIT-SPI1-00A0.dtbo  BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dtbo  BB-SPIDEV1A1-00A0.dts
BB-SPIDEV0-00A0.dtbo     BB-SPIDEV1-00A0.dts   BBB_SPI0-00A0.dtbo
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# echo BBB_SPI0 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots
```

3)  cat slots

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# cat /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots
0: 54:PF---
1: 55:PF---
2: 56:PF---
3: 57:PF---
4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
5: ff:P-O-L Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
7: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BBB_SPI0
```

Notice that there're now a new item 7, which is recently added.

4)now the device is there:

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# ls /dev/spi*
/dev/spidev1.0
```

If there's anything wrong in between, please post your error messages.

Comment: I got this question in my inbox, but it's not straightforward for me to figure out how to reply there. So here it is: the "file exists already" message happened to me only when I try to do it for more than one time. If you can, please post your output of "cat /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots" when you are having the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the HDMI uses the pins (28-31 on the P9 header) and hence, these pins are not available unless the HDMI DTS is

Answer (score 0):

- step 1 : `cd /lib/firmware`
- step 2 : `cd /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/`
- step 3 : `cat slots` (checking purpose)
- step 4 : `echo BB-SPIDEV0 > slots`
- step 5 : `cat slots`